# Neo4j/Cypher Delete with Where "Unknown identifier"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've made the mistake of being inconsistent with attribute types. For nodes of type "person", some have a string for the "external_id" property, and some have an int. I'd like to delete all nodes where the property is a string. The following query runs and seems to give a correct answer.

```
MATCH (n:person)
WHERE TOSTRING(n.external_id) = n.external_id
RETURN count(n)
```

However, when I try to delete those nodes using the following query, I get "Unknown identifier `n`.":

```
MATCH (n:person)
WHERE TOSTRING(n.external_id) = n.external_id
DELETE n
```

I'm new to Neo4j and Cypher, but this seems like it should be pretty straightforward. I've already deleted all of the relationships for these nodes. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems like a parse exception, can you try with `DETACH DELETE` instead of `DELETE`

Comment: I'm using Neo4j 2.2.5, so `DETACH` is not available. But I don't think that should matter, the nodes I'm trying to delete do not have any relationships.

Comment: Right, well I just tested in 2.3.1 and without DETACH DELETE it wasn't working either. I'll spin up a 2.2.5 version to check.

Comment: As a sanity check, in case there really still are relationships, try this: MATCH (n:person)
WHERE TOSTRING(n.external_id)= n.external_id
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE r, n;

Comment: That gives the same error: "Unknown identifier \`n\`."

Comment: I just tried a `CREATE` and then your query to `DELETE` or 2.2.5 and didn't get the error....  Were you able to reproduce this Chris?

Comment: @BrianUnderwood I did some testing yesterday. Turns out the issue only happens in `DELETE` clauses and only when there's a unique constraint on the `n.external_id` property. Smells like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5768 which was fixed by https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/5807

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a bug as @JeremyKendall suggested. It only came up because I have a uniqueness constraint on `person.external_id`. I found a simple workaround by copying the value of the `external_id` property into a temporary property on each `person` node (without a uniqueness constraint), and then deleting all nodes where that temporary property was a string.